# Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument when using DSolve. Why? Code is very simple, so I don't understand why

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
y[t_] = (x[t])^2;
T[t_] = 1/2 * ((x'[t])^2 +(y'[t])^2) * m;
h[t_] = y[t];
U[t_] = -(m * g * h[t]);
L = T[t] - U[t];
equation[t] = D[#1, #2] - D[D[#1, #3], t] &  [L, x[t], x'[t]];
xSolved[t] = DSolve[{equation[t] == 0, x[0] == -5, x'[0]==10}, x[t], t]
```

I just don't see it. The equation is properly calculated, the initial conditions are also correct. I don't know what's going on

Comment: I do not get the warning message in the title. I am in version 12.3, and if I restart my kernel using `Quit[]` and then run OP's code, I get some other messages, starting with: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found...

Comment: @user293787 Ok, now I get it, too. But what does this inverse function error mean?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's not a duplicate as the link you sent here does not solve my problem at all.

Comment: As someone else commented, your code does not produce `False` in the first argument. So it seems you do not have that problem at all. Can you post code that produces the problem?

Comment: I have not investigated the problem further. Maybe DSolve cannot solve the equation in this generality (or not without a bit of help) and one must use NDSolve. I assume the question was closed because the problem you had originally (and which is still the title of your question...) does in fact look like a duplicate. Edit: Just saw [this new equation by OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274759/animation-of-a-ball-rolling-up-and-down-a-parabola).